# Grub not trying to unlock LUKS partition

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, luks

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with full disk encryption with two partitions: EFI ESP and LUKS1 encrypted root partition (no separate /boot). After installing grub and rebooting, it just shows normal `grub >` prompt instead of asking for LUKS password and booting Ubuntu.  The kernel unlocks root filesystem by using LUKS keyfile in `/etc/luks/boot_os.keyfile`.

Grub configuration file in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` doesn't include `cryptomount` command so it's not even trying to unlock root partition:

```
search.fs_uuid ee03828b-76bc-4143-a2fb-f86719a90fca root cryptouuid/88251fdb112a4924a9c69892f17322e8 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

If I manually edit this file adding:

```
cryptomount -u 88251fdb112a4924a9c69892f17322e8
```

as the first line, grub asks for password and system boots fine.

How can I convince `grub-install` to include cryptomount in `grub.cfg` inside ESP, so that system upgrade won't break my system?

#### Other config files:

**`/etc/default/grub`**

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true

GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="luks cryptodisk"
```

**`/etc/fstab`**

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p2_crypt /                         ext4    errors=remount-ro  0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw                 0       0
UUID=6225-46A9  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

**`/etc/crypttab`**

```
# <target name> <source device>     <key file>  <options>
nvme0n1p2_crypt UUID=88251fdb-112a-4924-a9c6-9892f17322e8 /etc/luks/boot_os.keyfile luks,discard
```

**`/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook`**

```
KEYFILE_PATTERN=/etc/luks/*.keyfile
```

#### Partitions:

**`lsblk -e7 -f`**

```
NAME                FSTYPE      LABEL     UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                            
├─sda1              vfat        SYSTEM    E463-AB68                            
├─sda2                                                                         
├─sda3                                                                         
└─sda4              ntfs        WinRE_DRV B27667B5766778CD                     
nvme0n1                                                                        
├─nvme0n1p1         vfat                  6225-46A9                            /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2         crypto_LUKS           88251fdb-112a-4924-a9c6-9892f17322e8 
  └─nvme0n1p2_crypt ext4                  ee03828b-76bc-4143-a2fb-f86719a90fca /
```

Also, I don't care about dual-boot right now, so I disabled OS prober in `/etc/default/grub`.